# How do you query a MongoDB document where an array attribute is null or of zero length?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, size

I'd like to be able to query documents where an array attribute is either null or of zero length.  I've tried using $or, like

`{ things : { $or : [null, { $size : 0 } ] } }`

but MongoDB complains about it:

`{ "$err" : "invalid operator: $or", "code" : 10068 }`

It appears that MongoDB doesn't want to use $and or $or on array attributes.  I thought that simply querying for `{ things : { $size : 0 } }` would return documents that had non-null arrays of zero length as well as null arrays, but that doesn't appear to be true.

How can I issue a query to find all documents where an array attribute is null or of zero length?

Comment: Ok, based on the two responses so far, I think I wasn't as clear in my question as I could have been.  `things` is actually an attribute of a document, not a document itself.  IOW, if the collection is 'yuppies', then I want to query for atypical yuppies, that is, yuppies who don't have any things, and these three states all mean that a yuppy has no things:  a yuppy document with **no** `things` attribute, a yuppy document with a `things` attribute that is `null`, and a yuppy document with a `things` attribute that is `[]` (an empty array).  Does that make the question any clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `things` is `null`, it is not of type `Array`. It is of type `Null` which is its own data-type. `$size` only matches arrays. Any document where the field is something different than an array will never be matched by it.

Your syntax error is in how you use [the $or operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/). You don't use it *for* a field, you use it *as* a field.

```
db.collection.find({
   $or: [
       { things: { $size: 0 } },  // 0-elements array
       { things: null }           // field which is null
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in):

```javascript
db.test.find({things: {$in: [null, []]}})
```

That will also include docs with `things: [null]`.

Another way is to use [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) on the first element of the `things` array:

```javascript
db.test.find({'things.0': {$exists: false}})
```

That will find the docs where `things` does not have at least one element.  In contrast with the above, it will still include docs with `things: null` or `things: []`, but **not** `things: [null]`.

Comment: This also works in mongo shell.  I'll see about doing this in mongoose as well...